# test for post API receiving status code 200 instead of 201

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, django-rest-framework

My test for my post method API receive status code 200 but should 201 I tried to find where is problem but i couldn't. It would be easier if i would get error status 4xx but i have no idea why post method could receive code 200. My API view works fine so this must be problem with test code but I really don't have idea what may cause this problem. Maybe I'm wrong and status code 200 is ok, but I think that post method should receive status 201.

test_api.py

```
def test_post_logged_in(self):
    product = Product.objects.get(id=1)
    self.client.login(username='test', password='test123')
    data = {
        'nick': self.user.id,
        'rate': '1/5',
        'content': 'here is comment',
        'product': product.id
    }
    response = self.client.post(reverse('add_comments', kwargs={'id': product.id}), data, format='json')
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 201, f'expected Response code 201, instead get {response.status_code}')
```

views.py

```
class CreateComment(APIView):

def get_object(self, id):
    try:
        return Product.objects.get(id=id)
    except Product.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404

def get(self,request,  id):
    product = self.get_object(id)
    serializer = ProductSerializer(product)
    return Response(serializer.data)

def post(self, request,id):
    serializer = CommentSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save(nick=request.user, product=self.get_object(id))
        return Response(serializer.data)
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: Why don't you use a ModelViewSet?

Comment: ModelViewSet is much better? I recently learned making API views, and this is just best what i can currently make. But i'll check this ModelViewSet.

Comment: Yes, you should be using a ModelViewSet. You don't have to handle all the CRUD logic yourself. DRF has already done that for you. Check the viewset documentation here: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/6-viewsets-and-routers/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `post()`, you need to return [status.HTTP_201_CREATED](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/status-codes/#successful-2xx) if successful.

Try this:

```
def post(self, request,id):
    serializer = CommentSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save(nick=request.user, product=self.get_object(id))
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: Thanks very much, it works, I hate so much this kind of problems where something works but not in way I want and I cant find solution because there is no errors...

Comment: @Kuracha no problem! It happens to the best of us. I always like to work backwards to find the most likely culprit - in this case it was where the `Response()` was being returned (I assumed it defaults to a `200` success).

Also, if this worked for you, you can press the "check" icon under the votes, and it will let you mark your question as answered. This will also help others find the correct answer to the same problem. Best of luck!